# Swift Searching For Values inside values of Dictionary

Tags: json, swift, parsing, dictionary

I have a URL which my app fetches. it prints a dictionary with two keys but inside one of the keys is a lot of information I would like to get for my app.

The URL gets lots of information but not as a conventional dictionary.

this is a VERY simplified version:

```
["person": 
name: John
height: 187, "fruit": colour: red 
]
```

etc...

so I would just want to get the name of the person inside the key person but I am having trouble finding this.

Is there any way to do this? I have been trying JSON Parsing, for loops and I am stuck.

Edit:

it isn't a dictionary inside a dictionary. If you would like to see what I am working with. Just copy and paste this link. It is an example of what I am using. http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.burbn.instagram

I would need just the seller name or just the currency etc.

Code to read the link and print it:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchData { (dict, error) in
        print(dict!)
    }
}



func fetchData(completion: @escaping ([String:Any]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: link)!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            if let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]{
                completion(array, nil)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: The information is too simplified and too vague to suggest anything.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a dictionary within a dictionary, so if that's not the case you're gonna need to give a better explanation of the structure and how it's different. And if you have relevant code, please include it in the question itself, not as a link.

Comment: I included a link to the code im working with. In that code, it reveals a dictioary with two keys. Inside one of the key is all the info I want to extract but in certain parts. If you look at that code you will see

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The data you are fetching is JSON. In order to use it, you will have to decode it. The recommended way is using `JSONDecoder` in Swift.

First you will have to define your model, which correspond to the data model, and make it conform to `Codable` protocol:

```swift
struct App: Codable {
    var sellerName: String
    // Alternatively, if you don't want to use an enum, you can use a String.
    var currency: Currency

    enum Currency: String, Codable {
        case australianDollar = "AUD",
        case britishPound = "GBP",
        case euro = "EUR",
        case hongKongDollar = "HKD",
        case usDollar = "USD"
        // Complete this with all the currency…
    }
}

struct JSONResult: Codable {
    var resultCount: Int
    var results: [App]
}
```

Once this is done, you only have to edit your `fetchData` method so it returns an array `App` populated with the data you fetched.

**Swift 4 version:**

```swift
func fetchData(completion: @escaping (JSONResult?, Error?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        } else if let data = data {
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let result = try decoder.decode(JSONResult.self, from: data)
                completion(result, nil)
            } catch {
                print(error)
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Swift 5 version using `Result` type:**

```swift
func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Result<JSONResult, Error>) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        } else if let data = data {
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let result = try decoder.decode(JSONResult.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(result))
            } catch {
                print(error)
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

[More information about `JSONDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder)

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: @PeterDutton I also edited my answer for more precise information.

Answer (score -1):

Dictionary data is:

```
let dict = ["person": ["name": "John", "height": "187"], "fruit": ["colour": "red"]]
```

Suppose you need ***name*** of the person. So you can do it by the following way.

```
if let person = dict["person"], let name = person["name"] as? String {
    print (name)
}
```